# Error CS0571 'ResizeSettings.Scale.set', 'ImageBuilder.Current.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imageresizer

While debugging my asp.net core application,  I got these exception popping up:
Error   CS0571  'ResizeSettings.Scale.set', 'ResizeSettings.Quality.set' and 'ImageBuilder.Current.get' derived from the code snip show below

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureLocalPath);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Size size = this.CalculateDimensions(bitmap.Size, targetSize, ResizeType.LongestSide, true);
    ResizeSettings settings1 = new ResizeSettings();
    settings1.Width=size.Width;
    settings1.Height=size.Height;
    settings1.set_Scale(2); //error here
    settings1.set_Quality(this.mediaSettings_0.DefaultImageQuality); //error here
    ImageBuilder.get_Current().Build(bitmap, stream, settings1);//error here
    byte[] binary = stream.ToArray();
    this.SaveThumb(thumbLocalPath, thumbFileName, string.Empty, binary);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the ImageResizer library.

According to [the docs](http://documentation.imageresizing.net/doxygen/class_image_resizer_1_1_resize_settings.html#properties), `.Size` and `.Quality` are both properties.  And in C#, you set a property like this:

```
settings1.Scale = 2;
settings1.Quality = this.mediaSettings_0.DefaultImageQuality;
```

As for the `ImageBuilder` error, [the docs](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/managed) have an example of how you are supposed to use it (again, using properties the *right* way):

```
ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(bitmap, stream, settings1);
```

Your error message is very clearly telling you what is wrong.

I *highly* recomend reading through the documentation of libraries you decide to use and more importantly following some more tutorials on the basics of C#, you will need to use properties quite a bit in your development.

Comment: Thank you, i will do that, but now I nee my code refactored ASAP, that's why I'm asking those that are more knowledgeable,for help.

Comment: The settings1.Scale = 2 fix create another Error CS0266 of implicty conversion of an integer  Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'ImageResizer.ScaleMode', 
I will check into that, the rest works like a charm
Thank you again!